# SSRS 2008 Column Visability

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm currently getting used to working with SSRS 2008 as I previously used 2005. I have a data table set up with various columns and rows ect, one of the columns is a calculation of 3 of the others that need to be expandable to be viewed as a breakdown.

I've set to column vis by the group field which is fine, however it doesnt move the columns next to it in or out, it stays in the same place no matter how the toggle is set so i end up with a gap between columns. It seemed to do it automatically on 2005.

I cant find the setting that stops these columns being fixed in place.

Comment: Are you sure you set `Visibility = Hidden`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the Visibility option in the Properties section. Right-click on the column handle at the top and go into Column Visibility. Set it to Hide in there.